# Out of Memory on Compress-Archive. Set Max Memory? Enable Garbage Collection? Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Tags: powershell, zip, compress-archive

I have a problem in that my PowerShell Archive archive script crashes after consuming my entire machines memory using the `Compress-Archive` cmdlet.

The `for` loop added below really helped by only dealing with a few files at a time, but I am still getting "Out of Memory" errors on my large files I am trying to compress.

Is setting max PowerShell memory still an option? I understand set max memory may not work.
Also, I see garbage collection can be a solution. Where would one place the garbage collection and what would the appropriate syntax be? `[System.GC]::Collect()`?

```
$ArchiveContents = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\OneDrive | Sort-Object -Descending
for ($i=0; $i -le $ArchiveContents.Count; $i=$i+10) {
    Compress-Archive -Path $ArchiveContents.FullName[$i..($i+9)] -Update -DestinationPath \\Server011\Backup_Archive\CompanyData\Daily\OneDrive.zip -CompressionLevel Optimal
}
if (-not $?) {
    $SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
    #Redacted ?
    $smtp.Send($message)
} else {
    $SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
    #Redacted?
    $smtp.Send($message)
}
```

Comment: Consider the option to use a dedicated command line tool (7zip has one) over `Compress-Archive`. You might get it to work with `Compress-Archive` eventually, but if it (*ever*) gives Out-of-Memory errors then I'd say it's not exactly ready for prime time.

Comment: Yes, I noticed there is a request on UserVoice for the out of Memory Issues to be addressed, so you may be right that it is not ready for Prime Time. I am familar with 7Zip but I was experiencing some permission issues with it as well. I might give it another go however.

Comment: Should be a one-liner, since there is no need to split up the files you want to compress, and when you use the update operation (`7z u`) it will skip files that haven't changed. In place of `$?`, use a `$LASTEXITCODE` check.

Comment: Thanks so much! That will be very helpful!